# Can't import org.apache.jena.rdf.model - package does not exist

Tags: jena

I'm trying to get started on jena basics, but when I import the package with

```
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.*;
```

and compile with

```
javac -cp "~/api/apache-jena-3.10.0/lib/*:." Foo.java
```

I just get the error on the import line that the package does not exist.

I've double checked that the folder is where it should be, it's freshly installed, I've exported the path with

```
export JENA_HOME=~/api/apache-jena-3.10.0
export PATH=$PATH:$JENA_HOME/bin
```

as suggested by the jena homepage, confirmed that it's installed with "sparql --version", and tested that "cd $JENA_HOME" works as expected. I can't find any post with the same issue either.

Would very much appreciate some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expansion rules for `~` and `*` are such that `~` is replaces with your home directory outside a "" string, but left alone inside and `*` is matched to the file system when outside "" but not inside.

You want to leave `*` alone, so Java sees it (it has special meaning to `-cp` - it only matches jar files).

Try "$HOME/api/apache-jena-3.10.0/lib/*" or ~/api/apache-jena-3.10.0/lib/*

In the first, `$var` rules apply and `$HOME` is replaced and the `*` is untouched.

In the second, the `~` is replaced and the `*` is escaped, so it is left alone. Be careful it does not expand later when used. If you assign to a variable e.g. in `export` use "" around any use of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Export the JENA_HOME variable's path as

```
export JENA_HOME=~/api/apache-jena-3.10.0/lib/*
```

Comment: Try running with this                                                                                          
    javac -cp "~/api/apache-jena-3.10.0/lib/\*" Foo.java

Comment: You can't put ~ inside "" and have it expand. And you don't want the "*" to expand. Try `"$HOME/api/apache-jena-3.10.0/lib/*"` or `~/api/apache-jena-3.10.0/lib/\*`

Comment: Finally, it compiles! Thank you very much :)  Did not know about ~ and "".

Comment: Great - turned into an answer for the record - please check and accept.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, because according to the pom.xml

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <!-- Use resource filtering to replace references to the artifactId in 
                the plugin.xml file -->
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

So we should put the jar files in the resourcse files, and then the project will be compiled normally